# ASP.NET form may be too long, not getting read by our server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We have a huge grid and we have checkboxes and same textboxes.

We are experiencing weird behavior, one example is that the buttons on the bottom do cause a postback but doing the step debugging reveals that the event handlers are not being called.

so we moved the buttons to the top of the page and now the event handlers are being called.

we also noticed that in the same request, if we check some items at the top and some items at the bottom the top items do get updated and the bottoms items do not.

so we did this

```
        string strReturn = "";
        foreach (string strKey in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {

            if (strKey.IndexOf(".x", 1) < 1 && strKey.IndexOf(".y", 1) < 1)
                strReturn += "<br> "  + strKey + " : " + Request.Form[strKey];
        }
        Response.Write(strReturn);
```

what did this is print all form variables and it turns out there is a cutoff. While viewing source we can see the form elements (textboxes, checkboxes) correctly, when submitting them they are not being seen by our code. So at some point the request is being truncated, and it affects the form element including the buttons as we discussed above.

We did disable viewstate for the grid and it still didn't work. We also have this in our web config file to maximize the request size, we used this for file upload too
    httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="300000000000"

We know our code is looping enough times but the values we are getting are null since they do not exist in the request.

This is working on one development machine but not on the production server or the other development machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly how many key/value pairs are being included in the POST?  It sounds like *a lot*.

Comment: there's also the remote possibility that some names/ids are getting repeated maybe?

Comment: there is about 1500 fields.. the issue was that the form elements were truncated at 1000 as the answer suggested. the suggested fix resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iis likely that you're running into an issue caused by the update described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-100).

> Microsoft security update MS11-100 limits the maximum number of form
>   keys, files, and JSON members to 1000 in an HTTP request.

If you can reduce the size of the grid via paging, that might eliminate/alleviate the issue.  Otherwise, you can increase the max in your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="1000" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

More info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661403).

Comment: Not sure what kind of data they are using but your suggestion of paging is probably the best. No user wants to go through thousands of rows looking for what they need, or even waiting that long for a page to render. Having a page with 25-50 rows on it with the ability to sort will reduce the load on EVERYTHING including the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys this fixed it      <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="1000" />